# VI automatically pastes in last deleted line when opening file

Tags: unix, vi

I use vi to edit files, but recently everytime i enter/open a file in vi it automatically pastes in the last line i deleted with the keyboard shortcut 'dd'. Is there any way i can disable this odd behavior?

Comment: "vi" or "vim"? If Vim, try with `$ vim -Nu NONE`.

Comment: i use vi, not vim

Comment: Then there is no point using the vim tag.

Comment: I doubt it's `vi` to be honest. Some distros launch `vim`. What does the interface show on startup (e.g. after running the command above does it say in the center)? What does `$ which vi` output? When running vi, what does `:version` show? I would make sure no runcoms at all are affecting it, so use wiped .bashrc, .input, .profile, .vim, .vimrc, etc...

Comment: more appropriate to [vi.se] . Good luck.